# Standardization of a random variable with normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

Let $$X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$$
\begin{align*}
 P\bigg(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \leqslant x\bigg) &= P(X \leqslant x\cdot\sigma + \mu)\\
  &= \int_{-\infty}^{x\cdot\sigma + \mu}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\cdot\exp\bigg(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg)\,dx}\\
  &= \int_{-\infty}^{x\cdot\sigma + \mu}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\cdot\exp\Bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\bigg(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\bigg)^2\Bigg)\,dx}
\end{align*}
We substitute with $$\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} = y \quad\Rightarrow\quad \frac{1}{\sigma}\,dx = dy \quad\Rightarrow\quad dx = \sigma \,dy$$ so:
\begin{align*}
 &= \int_{-\infty}^y {\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\cdot\exp\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\cdot y^2\bigg)\cdot\sigma \, dy}\\
  &= \int_{-\infty}^{y}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot\exp\bigg(-\frac{y^2}{2}\bigg) \,dy}\\
  &= \Phi(y)
\end{align*}
Therefore $$\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \sim N(0, 1)$$
Is that correct?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct.

But I wouldn't go from $\dfrac{dx}\sigma=dy$ to $dx = \sigma\,dy$.  Instead, since the integral is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\mu+x\sigma} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(\frac{-1}2\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right) \frac{dx}\sigma,
$$
I'd just put $dy$ in place of $\dfrac{dx}\sigma$.